# Wordpress and PHP 5.3

Tags: php, wordpress, deprecated

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to why `wp-admin/options-general.php` won't load on my Wordpress installation in PHP 5.3? If I enable debugging and then have PHP report errors, I do get deprecation errors, but they don't seem relevant. Further, if I fix these errors, the page still does not load.

The top bar and several navigation boxes load, but nothing inside the central frame?

I am running dotdeb's PHP 5.3

Output with `WP_DEBUG` and `error_reporting(0)`:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/willyum/willyum.info/blog/wp-includes/cache.php on line 103

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/willyum/willyum.info/blog/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 171

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/willyum/willyum.info/blog/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 407

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/willyum/willyum.info/blog/wp-includes/query.php on line 61

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/willyum/willyum.info/blog/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1133

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/willyum/willyum.info/blog/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 617
```

Comment: Do you have the latest version of WP?

Comment: serverfault.com will be able to help you better with this. It's not a programming question.

Comment: @echo: I have the latest from wordpress.org today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, wordpress uses lots of [@ operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) to avoid the display of errors... So, many of those are not displayed, event if `error_reporting` is activated :-(

(That's one of the reasons that @ operator is evil... )

Maybe using the [scream extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/scream) on your testing machine, to disabled the @ operator, could help ?

*Still, I've just tried wordpress on PHP 5.3, and that page seems to load fine... I'm using a 2.8.x version, btw*

Comment: Then this has to be specific to me — I can't find it on Wordpress.org either. I'll try removing some @'s.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling all Plugins that you have installed. If it solves the problem, then try to enable each Plugin one my one to find out the offending Plugin.

You can also use wp-devel Plugin to find out the function trace. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-devel/

Comment: But I haven't any plugins installed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Wordpress debug (Pear and more) plugins?](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=debug) would help? (I haven't used any myself.)