# Tried to Move a WordPress site now I get these weird errors

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, migration

I moved a wordpress site from a shared environment to a dedicated virtual server on media temple. I got a blank page at first, but I'm getting these weird errors when I turn error reporting on.

How do I fix it?

Site URL: https://64.207.147.116/

**Error Messages**

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/herondance.org/httpdocs/wp-settings.php on line 219 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/herondance.org/httpdocs/wp-settings.php on line 234 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/herondance.org/httpdocs/wp-settings.php on line 241 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/herondance.org/httpdocs/wp-settings.php on line 248 Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/herondance.org/httpdocs/wp-settings.php on line 273 Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/herondance.org/httpdocs/wp-settings.php on line 27 Notice: Undefined variable: wp_version in /var/www/vhosts/herondance.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/1-click-retweetsharelike/la-click-and-share-utility-fns.php on line 4 Notice: Undefined index: PATH_INFO in /var/www/vhosts/herondance.org/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/blip-slideshow/blip.php on line 723 Notice: register_uninstall_hook was called **incorrectly**. Only a static class method or function can be used in an uninstall hook. (This message was added in version 3.1.) in /var/www/vhosts/herondance.org/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I went into the database with phpmyadmin and disabled all plugins. I then installed them one by one in the backend and presto. Live, working site. Thanks for all the responses though.

Answer (score 2):

Check what version of WordPress and PHP you are using. It looks like you might be using a really old version of WordPress that uses features of PHP that are no longer supported. If that is the case I would recommend upgrading WordPress to the latest version.

A stop gap measure would be to disable these warnings by putting the following line of code at the beginning of the index.php file in your web root.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

This will prevent those messages from being displayed, but you really shouldn't ignore them.

Comment: PHP: 5.3.4 / WP: WordPress 3.1.1./ They both seem pretty update to me. I turned on the error reporting. It's much better than having to deal with the blank white page. Then, I have some idea of what's going on.

Comment: Try reading the post sounds similar to your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242871/wordpress-and-php-5-3